# FastAPI: modifying response code while preserving automatic validation

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

In the below code I have a created a post route that sends back an identical response irrespective of the input.

The input and output is automatically validated because I've referenced pydantic BaseModel in the appropriate places.

In your [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-change-status-code/) you have examples of how to modify the response code.

Two questions:

- how would I conditionally modify the response code here while preserving response validation (which I place in the decorator)?
- Anything I could do to clean up my code? What is the preferred way to provide default values to the input? Can you provide an example?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import UrlStr, IPvAnyAddress

...

class Bar(BaseModel):
    url = UrlStr
    ip = IPvAnyAddress


@app.post('/foo', response_model=Bar)
async def foo_endpoint(request: Bar):
    response = Bar(**{ip='111.111.111.111', url='www.google.com'})
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'modify the response code here conditionally', can you provide an example?

For your second question, setting defaults on your Pydantic models;

```
class FooBase(BarModel):
    attribute_x: Optional[str] = None
    attribute_y: Optional[bool] = False
    attribute_z: Optional[str] = None
```